# Best way to open mailto: TAG in gmail

Tags: html, gmail

Can any one please let me know that, i need to open a gmail `Compose Mail` popup via `mailto` TAG. It always open the Outlook Express for new mail.

Comment: You can set this in FireFox via preferences and in defaults - you will have to scroll down to see the gmail option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mailto:` syntax of a hyperlink will open the default email application on your machine. There is no way you can force it to open gmail. You can use a regular link though, without the `mailto:` syntax.

Comment: please check that...
http://lifehacker.com/392287/set-firefox-3-to-launch-gmail-for-mailto-links

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a plugin for chrome which lets you do this:

http://skaelede.hu/?e=chromemailer&lg=en